# apache sends me to other/"nearest" page, when virtual host is not enabled?

Tags: server, apache2

So I have a server with ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and apache.

Everything is working fine... except for one thing.

When a webpage has a DNS record pointing to my server.. and if the host is not available (not enabled) on my server... for some reason, my apache just sends the request to the "nearest" virtual host on the server?

So lets say, we have 2 domains with dns records pointing at my server.

www.ex1.dk
www.ex2.dk

but only ex2.dk is enabled.

then when someone try to access ex1.dk, they will just get shown the www.ex2.dk.... but still with ex1.dk, in the adressbar...

What I want, should be that apache sends a 404, not found... and not just sends me to some other page.

Have anyone tried this? or know how to fix this issue??

Comment: Apache on the host that are down don't send you anywhere. Either it is your browser that plays with you, ot the other server has taken over the ip-address - by it self, or via the hypervisor.

Comment: I am not using any hypervisor... the setup is simular til shared hosting... not a VPS system....  I can't really figure out why it is doing it, since I have made other friends try to go to the same links, and gets the same result as me... which can only point out, something wrong in the apache conf.

Answer (score 0):

You need a default virtual host, which will catch all requests that are not caught by any of the other virtual hosts. Just create a new `VirtualHost` block in your Apache configuration, preferably with no `ServerName` directive, and make sure it appears before any other `VirtualHost` block. If you use the default `sites-available` infrastructure in Ubuntu, put it in a file named `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` or suchlike.

Comment: I have now made a 000-default.conf, and enabled the site. I wrote it like this: <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName Default
        Redirect 404 /
        
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost> I have removed the DNS record untill now... but I will try and remake it, and check if these works...

Comment: Nope... stil doesn't work.... it still sends me to the other website....